# How to make if-else statement in JAPE right hand side?

Tags: java, annotations, gate, java-annotations

I am new to JAPE (Java Annotation Pattern Engine), a part of GATE.

I have already made some rules in LHS that result some tags (say tag a, b, and c) in text.

My text consists of several parts, and I would like to classify each part based on generated tags.

**As for illustration:**

```
<record id=001>
lorem <a>ipsum</a> dolor sit amet
</record>
<record id=002>
consectetur <b>adipiscing</b> elit, sed do eiusmod <a>tempor</a> incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua
</record>
<record id=003>
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis <a>nostrud</a> exercitation <c>ullamco</c> laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
</record>
```

As you can see that each record can contain more than one tags generated in `LHS`.

I would like to classify each record based on the tag inside it.

Say, if a record contains tag `a`, then classify it as A. If it contains `a` and `b`, classify it as A, assuming `a` is stronger than `b`.

I notice that I should manipulate this in RHS but I don't have an idea how to write this.

Could you please give me a clue or something?

Thanks.

Regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to build an if-else statement using JAPE grammar, it is not always required using Java in RHS.

When writing the rules, it can often be convenient to divide processing in multiple stages: each stage produces some results, which can then be passed to the next stages. So, based on what you just described, the data processing could be divided in the following three phases.

1. **RecordFinder**, which returns the records within the document, ie `Record` annotations.
2. **TagFinder**, which returns tags `a` and `b` within the document.
3. **Intersection**: it searches for tags `a` and `b` within the records.

File **Main.jape**

```
MultiPhase: Main
Phases: 
RecordFinder
TagFinder
Intersection
```

File **RecordFinder.jape**

This phase is able to annotate the records in your document. The only rule of this JAPE file reads *tokens* (ie `Token` annotations returned by the tokeniser) as input and finds the records (ie tags `record`) within the document, and finally it returns `Record` annotations.

Note that, in the *Options*, the *control* is set as *first*, because the aim is to find the first occurrence of a sequence containing a token `<record>`, followed by one or more other tokens, followed by a token `</record>`.

```
Phase: RecordFinder
Input: Token
Options: control = first debug = true


// The following rule is able to find the sentence within a record
Rule: RuleToFindRecord
(
    ({Token.string == "<"} {Token.string == "record"} ({Token})* {Token.string == ">"})
    ({Token})*
    ({Token.string == "<"} {Token.string == "/"} {Token.string == "record"} {Token.string == ">"})
):match
-->
:match.Record = { rule = "RuleToFindRecord" }
```

File **TagFinder.jape**

This phase reads *tokens* as input and finds tags `a` and `b` within the text, and finally it returns `a` and `b` annotations.

```
Phase: TagFinder
Input: Token
Options: control = first debug = true


// The following rule is able to find the tag "a" within the document.
Rule: RuleToFindTag_a
(
    (
        ({Token.string == "<"} {Token.string == "a"} {Token.string == ">"})
        ({Token})*
        ({Token.string == "<"} {Token.string == "/"} {Token.string == "a"} {Token.string == ">"})
    )
    |
    ({Token.string == "<"} {Token.string == "a"} {Token.string == "/"} {Token.string == ">"})
):match
-->
:match.a = { rule = "RuleToFindTag_a" }


// The following rule is able to find the tag "b" within the document.
Rule: RuleToFindTag_b
(
    (
        ({Token.string == "<"} {Token.string == "b"} {Token.string == ">"})
        ({Token})*
        ({Token.string == "<"} {Token.string == "/"} {Token.string == "b"} {Token.string == ">"})
    )
    |
    ({Token.string == "<"} {Token.string == "b"} {Token.string == "/"} {Token.string == ">"})
):match
-->
:match.b = { rule = "RuleToFindTag_b" }
```

File **Intersection.jape**

This phase reads the annotations `Record`, `a` and `b` as input and searches for tags `a` or `b` within `Record`. Read [this](https://gate.ac.uk/wiki/jape-repository/operators.html#section-4.) as reference about *contains* and *within* operators (I used one of these operators in the following rules).

```
Phase: Intersection
Input: Record a b
Options: control = first debug = true


// A record matches with this rule if it contains both tag a and tag b.
Rule: Rule_1
(
    {Record contains a, Record contains b}
):match
-->
:match.Record_with_both_tags = { rule = "Rule_1" }


// A record matches with this rule if it contains tag a.
Rule: Rule_2
(
    {Record contains a}
):match
-->
:match.Record_with_tag_a = { rule = "Rule_2" }
```